# edit html page in chrome developer tools

Tags: html, edit, google-chrome-devtools

I have a webpage which I am analyzing in chrome. I want to add elements and mess around with the html of that page.

I tried using chrome developers tools for that, I went to the elements tab and I clicked on "edit as html". Over there when I write things, they are not updated immediately. 
In Firebug when you are editing html, you can see the changes occur simultaneously on the webpage. Can I achieve the same in chrome developer tools ?

**Edit**

Please tell me also how to achieve the same simultaneous modification of js files.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As soon as you click off the text editor your changes will be applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in firebug it will show as you tpe . in developer tools you have to type and focus out !

i think in IE it is like that  too

Comment: what about editing javascript. Can I change js files in firebug/chrome and see those changes in effect immediately ?

Comment: @user590849 You should just need to press Ctrl+S (in the code editor) and the changes should take place immediately.